# Mac OSX and Google Meet - Permissions being blocked for full screen sharing

Tags: macos, mac, google-chrome, google

We are seeing a growing number of instances of this issue:  Users have Macs.  They use Google Meet, and have been using it.  Randomly, Google Meet will not work with screen sharing within the meeting.  As this is typically governed within the Security & Privacy - Screen Recording section, you look there.  Google Chrome is listed with permissions.  The "fix" is to remove Google Chrome from the screen sharing.  Then manually add it back.  Now it works fine.

Question:  Any reports as to why this is happening.  Chrome is up to date, as is the MacOS.  This rates up there with "Turn it off and on again" solution that doesn't fly with clients.

Comment: This reads more like an answer than a question right now. Also, it has come up before.